# Cannot remove folders from django media root

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, file-permissions, django-media

I'm trying to delete the directory from `MEDIA_ROOT` with [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html). After I have processed the files in the `MEDIA_ROOT`, I just want to clean up the directory along with the files in it. But getting permission denied error while using [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html). The default user is `myuser`. Is there a way to set folder with delete permission. I even tried the following permission in `settings.py`.

```
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = 0o755
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
```

[image: file-permission]

Answer (score 0):

Manually you can simply run the following command

```
sudo rm -r <path_to_MEDIA_ROOT>
```

If you want to still go with shutil and not use sudo, then you have to ensure to have write permissions to `MEDIA_ROOT` directory and then use

```
shutil.rmtree(path_to_MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to delete the directory and all its contents.